# add dash in inputbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, inputbox

How can I make a input field that automatically adds a dash after six digits.
Is should also only be possible to write numbers in the input field.

Can this be done using jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Borrowing code from this post: [How to allow only numeric (0-9) in HTML  inputbox using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995183/how-to-allow-only-numeric-0-9-in-html-inputbox-using-jquery?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top)

You can add a condition to capture length.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#txtboxToFilter").keydown(function(event) {
        // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, and enter
        if ( event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 9 || event.keyCode == 27 || event.keyCode == 13 || 
             // Allow: Ctrl+A
            (event.keyCode == 65 && event.ctrlKey === true) || 
             // Allow: home, end, left, right
            (event.keyCode >= 35 && event.keyCode <= 39)) {
                 return;
        }
        else {
            // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
            if (event.shiftKey || (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) && (event.keyCode < 96 || event.keyCode > 105 )) {   
                event.preventDefault(); 
            }   
        }

        if(  $("#txtboxToFilter").val().length == 6 )
       {
            event.target.value = event.target.value + "-";
       }
    });
});
</script>

<form>

<input type="text" id="txtboxToFilter">

</form>
```

Comment: You may want to modify the keyup handler to add a dash every 6 digits. This only adds the dash after the FIRST six digits, but you get the picture.

Comment: It works. But it don't add the dash if you keep pressing just one digit on your keyboard.

Comment: You are right stefan. I always forget that users could just hold down a key...Anyways, i'll update the post

Comment: This breaks pasting: ctrl+v does not work, and other forms of pasting override `keyup`, so get nor filtered, nor formatted.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('#inputFieldId').keydown(function(event) {
            var enteredValue = jQuery(this).val();
            if ( event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 9 || event.keyCode == 27 || event.keyCode == 13 || 
                   (event.keyCode == 65 && event.ctrlKey === true) || (event.keyCode >= 35 && event.keyCode <= 39) || 
                   (event.keyCode>=48 && event.keyCode<=57) || (event.keyCode>=96 && event.keyCode<=105)) // allow numbers
                {
                   if(enteredValue.length==6 && ((event.keyCode>=48 && event.keyCode<=57) || (event.keyCode>=96 && event.keyCode<=105)))
                   {
                    jQuery(this).val(enteredValue+"-")
                   }
               }
            else
            {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
```

now corrected the code, try this.

Comment: Yes it works fine. But it dont add the dash if you just hold down one key.

Comment: now i corrected the code and checking other conditions as per Blaise answer. I have tested the code and it allows number only with hold down key.

Comment: Thanks Bhushan. Work fine now =)

Comment: Could it also be possible to type from the numpad?

Comment: It isn't. Think I need to add this or something like that: event.keyCode>=48 && event.keyCode<=57

Comment: can you do one thing, add alert in the script and read event.keycode when entering from numpad and modify the script accordingly.

Comment: Added: || (event.keyCode>=96 && event.keyCode<=105) // to the first and second if condition.